# Do I need explicitly grunt in package.json when using sails

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, sails.js

I have `sails` app and main package.json as below.
Do I really need all those grunt here if sails has them also. Especially if sails has grunt in version 0.4.5 and here I have 0.4.2
Anyway without grunt entry in main app package.json. There is an error after `sails lift`. This looks like a some inconsistency.

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "~0.8.4",
    "grunt": "0.4.2",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "~0.10.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jst": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "0.11.1",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
    "grunt-sails-linker": "~0.9.5",
    "grunt-sync": "~0.0.4",
    "include-all": "~0.1.3",
    "mongodb": "^2.0.41",
    "rc": "~0.5.0",
    "sails": "git://github.com/balderdashy/sails.git",
    "sails-disk": "~0.10.0",
    "sails-mongo": "^0.11.2"
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to keep them. What ever the error **if you want to grunt integration**. Try to remove them and remove the `node_modules` folder of you project and run `npm install`, you will see that you won't be able to run grunt task like  `default` because all plugins needed are not registered in the `package.json`. You are the creator of the project so when you create your app with `sails new app`, all npm dependencies of your project are aliases and points to `node_modules` folder of sails node modules installed globally.

I give you an example to illustrate the problem :
all dependencies are not integrated to a versioning system (best practices), then the `node_modules` folder will be ignore. If a collaborator pull the project, he have to run `npm install` to install all project dependencies, and if you have removed all grunt plugins from the `package.json`, he won't be able to run grunt tasks because all plugins needed are not registered in the `package.json`.

**If you want to disable grunt integration**, add this to your `.sailsrc` file :

```
"hooks": {
    "grunt": false
}
```

**To understand how grunt is integrated to sails**, I recommend you to read the documentation and especially these sections :
- [disabling-grunt](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/assets/disabling-grunt)
- [task-automation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/assets/task-automation)
- [default-tasks](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/assets/default-tasks)